# Como testar Web Service no Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-service, testes

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, estou fazendo um [web-service](/questions/tagged/web-service) server com minha aplicação [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), estou usando a `gem wash-out`, entendi como ela funciona e consegui colocar meu web-service para rodar, porém gostaria de saber como testar o meu servidor, já procurei vários tutoriais e nenhum me ajudou.

Por exemplo:

```
 soap_action "novo_cadastro",
      :args   => {:titulo => :string, :descricao => :string },
      :return => :xml

  def novo_cadastro
    cad = Cadastro.new(titulo: params[:titulo], descricao: params[:descricao])
    if cad.save
      render xml: cad
    else
      render :soap => nil
    end
  end
```

Como testar isso?

Grato.

Comment: que tipo de teste você está em duvida de como fazer teste unitário ou teste de integração?

Comment: Eu tenho o meu controller funcionando, criei um cliente e ele só conecta, faz requisições e obtém resposta, porém esse foi só um teste, no meu servidor real, preciso utilizar a técnica TDD para ter a garantia de que ele estará funcionando, não consigo testar as ações do controller, na verdade não sei como, o cliente é tranquilo de testar, mas e o servidor?

Comment: comece fazendo os testes unitários de seu servidor,  o segredo de um bom teste é cobrir o máximo possível do código e testar bem os casos limites do seu programa, começa quebrando seu programa em pequenos testes de forma simples. Test não tem milagre, tem q parar estudar e fazer. Sugiro se você estiver com pressa os cursos de teste do codeschool.

Comment: @FelipeBergamo Eu sei fazer testes, o modelo está com cobertura de testes 100%, a minha dúvida é  como testar essa função acima, que só é acessada por um client.

Comment: como o `wash-out` é baseado na gem `Savon`, dá uma olhada na gem: [savon_spec](https://github.com/savonrb/savon_spec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo da página do [`WashOut`](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out):

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'savon'

class NovoCadastroTeste < ActiveSupport::TestCase

    test "cadastro com sucesso" do

        cliente = Savon::Client.new(wsdl: "http://localhost:3000/novo_cadastro/wsdl")

        cliente.operations # Retorna operações possíveis.

        resultado = client.call(:novo_cadastro, message: { :titulo => "titulo", :descricao => "descricao" })

        # Verifique se a resposta está correta.

        resultado = resultado.to_hash

        assert resultado[:sucesso]
    end
end
```

Você deve importar a gem do savon no seu Gemfile, assim:

```
gem 'savon'
```